# Is it okay to store the IPv4 address as a number (without dots)?

Tags: ip, ipv4

I'm using public-ip npm package to get the IP address in the client side, then I store it for authentication purposes, for now, I'm storing it as a number and not as a string, for example:
"123.123.12.123" is stored as "12312312123".
if the IPv4 address format is constant there will be no problem, but I noticed that for example if I use the 4G network to access my website it will give me other IP formats as: xxx.xx.xx.xx or xxx.xxx.xx.xx.
Is there any way to know the original format of the IP after converting it to number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses as numbers, but not in the way you describe. Technically an IP address is a number and it's converted to readable form for us humans.

You can use functions like inet_pton and inet_ntop (printable to number, and number to printable respectively) to get the actual 32 or 128 bit number you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I also found a npm package called ip-to-int which converts in the 2 ways.